# Possible to config spring security to give access to some users from ldap?

Tags: spring, spring-security, ldap

I wonder if its possible to config spring security with a ldap as authentication provider so that only some of the users in the ldap is getting access? Is it possible to config it so that I can write in the names of the users that is giving access?

Im using Spring 3.1

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is posible, see the spring [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ldap.html). Your second question is not clear for me. Do you mean that, once the user from ldap is authenticated you want to display the user name? Thas is possible.